# React Native unable to to set AsyncStorage after Fetch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, mobile

## this question has been answered, you can ignore that and click away

i am making my app using react native expo, and after successfully login, my server return an token an i want to store it in the AsyncStorage, this is my code:

```
import { Alert, AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

export const login_as_student = async (code, password, navigation) => {
  return fetch("http://192.168.47.102:5000/users/login/student", {
    // Windows + CMD
    // Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ code, password }),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((json) => {
      const { currentUser, token } = json;
      console.log(json);

      if (token && currentUser) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem("token", token)
          .then((value) => console.log("token", value))
          .catch((error) => console.log(error));

        return navigation.navigate("Darshboard");
      } else {
        console.log(json);
        Alert.alert(json.message);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      Alert.alert(err.message);
    });
};
```

and this is the result:

```
Object {
  "currentUser": Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "5f8be6bf0220db23d096ca14",
    "activated": false,
    "code": "16020503",
    "fullname": "Đỗ Xuân An ",
    "password": "$2b$10$PQ5EAc3Vkn1WT00uKadYi.ue2UR1lRBfSeF.cXgZps2pqejV4bAUy",
    "profileImage": "https://avataaars.io/?accessoriesType=Prescription01&avatarStyle=Circle&clotheColor=Blue02&clotheType=BlazerSwet 
er&eyeType=WinkWacky&eyebrowType=FlatNatural&facialHairColor=Platinum&facialHairType=MoustacheFancy&hairColor=Platinum&hatColor=PastelRed&mouthType=Vomit&skinColor=Brown&topType=LongHairMiaWallace",
    "role": "student",
    "vnumail": "16020503@vnu.edu.vn",
  },
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJkYXRhIjoiXCI1ZjhiZTZiZjAyMjBkYjIzZDA5NmNhMTRcIiIsImlhdCI6MTYwMzU1ODYyOSwiZXhwIjoxNjAzNjQ1MDI5fQ.cxOHxddB_ha94ZGXY_XLcCs1MgDJHhZDgbl4GFOzk80",
}
token null
```

as you can see, i received a json which contains 2 objects is token and currentUser, after that i stored it in the AsyncStorage but it returns null, i am totally newbie with React Native, thank you for help me out and have a good day :)

## update:

thanks everyone, i have been figured it out that the AsyncStorage is no longer imported from "react-native", it is now imported from "@react-native-community/async-storage", have a good day

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **await** before AsyncStorage.setItem()

Modify your code like this:

```
.then(async (json) => { // Make this async
  const { currentUser, token } = json;
  console.log(json);

  if (token && currentUser) {
   await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", token) // add await here
      .then((value) => console.log("token", value))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    return navigation.navigate("Darshboard");
  } else {
    console.log(json);
    Alert.alert(json.message);
  }
})
```

Comment: thank you for help me out, i have figured it out why, and i updated it on the question, have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are getting right (non NULL) token and currentUser values after destructuring?

If you are getting null, wrap the statement within parenthesis
`({currentUser, token} = json)`

Also, an advice, better mask or hide the token value or any other sensitive info before posting :)

Comment: thank you for help me out, i have figured it out why, and i updated it on the question, have a good day